# Multiple select boxes(pillbox) using select2

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I am using multi select option(pillbox) using select2.
Using the above code just gives me a basic dropdown box .
Q: I am not able to get the search box where the user can type.
Thank you for taking time and looking into my query!
Here is the code.

---

```
<html>
<head>
<title>multiple select</title>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>Multiple select example
    <div class="selectRow">
        <!-- Using data-placeholder below to set place holder value versus putting in configuration -->
        <select id="multipleSelectExample" data-placeholder="Select an option" multiple>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
            <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            <option value="4">Option 4</option>
            <option value="5">Option 5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        $("#multipleSelectExample").select2();
    }
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following i think you need to place the jQuery script tag before the select2. And also i think you need to use a more recent version of jQuery.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>multiple select</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<p>Multiple select example</p>
<div class="selectRow">
    <!--     Using data-placeholder below to set place holder value versus putting in configuration-->
    <select class="" id="multipleSelectExample" data-placeholder="Select an option" multiple="">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5">Option 5</option>
    </select>
</div>
</body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            $('#multipleSelectExample').select2();
        }
    );
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Sam. I did try using latest jquery version and copyied the script tag ...I am not getting the expected results. Thanks.

Comment: Hey Dee, the above is working locally for me. Might be worth copying the above into a new html file to see if it works for you. If so should just be a matter of comparing against your own.